# Interactions are not available for this element in Appium

Tags: appium, appium-ios

I am getting the following message while identifying element the highlighted element in “Appium”.

**Appium:** 1.7.1
**Device:** IPhone X (12.0 & Simulator)
**Java client:** 1.6.1
**Xcode:** V 10

- **Interactions are not available for this element.**

[Appium- IOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nereW.png)

Aim to read the content of the element using .gettext() method.

**Logic used.**

// Explicit wait with 30 seconds.

return driver.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(WebElement))).getText();

**WebElement used.**

1, /XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name=“Event Manager”]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nereW.png)/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther[3]/XCUIElementTypeOther

2, //XCUIElementTypeOther[3]/XCUIElementTypeOther

None of the above return the text that are there in the image. Also no exception/error thrown as well.

Any help on what else can be done to read the web element?